# Top voted questions by topic

Tags: discussion

Okay, so this isn't really a question, but I just thought I'd compile this and share it, so we can use it to show what hot topics are. These aren't in any particular order.

- Lord of the Rings: 5, including 3 questions with more than 1K visitors
- 1 Hitchhiker's Guide
- 1 Star Wars, with 3K visitors
- 1 2001, with 3K visitors
- 1 List
- 2 StarGate: including a 2K visitor
- 1 Matrix
- 1 Dr. Who
- 1 Battlestar Galactica, with 2K visitors
- 1 Story Identification

Of these, it looks like Stargate and Lord of the Rings gets the most votes, and bring in alot of users to boot.

Comment: If you wanted to post stuff this like this often, and perhaps some other information that would be of general interest (e.g. SFF news), perhaps we could have a SE blog, like http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: @Tony: It could be interesting. I don't really have much of a desire to do this very often, but I thought it was interesting, for a one time stat.

Comment: @Tony for more information regarding the blog set up, [have a look at this answer by Rebecca on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91407/area-51-for-blogs/91509#91509)

Comment: @Ivo opened http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/586/is-it-worth-having-a-site-blog

Answer (score 1):

When looking at what questions bring in the most users there are only [4 notable questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/47/notable-question) (Over 2500 views), 2 of them are about [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars).  There are [9 Star Wars questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstar-wars%5D%20views:500) with over 500 views and [4 with over 1000](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstar-wars%5D%20views:1000) out of 56 total [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) questions.

The [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) tag has the most questions (86) but only [7 with over 500 views](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstar-trek%5D%20views:500) and [none over 1000](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstar-trek%5D%20views:1000).

Our in house Star Wars guru is [DVK](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:976+[star-wars]) and for Star Trek it's [Mark Trapp](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:366+[star-trek])

Answer (score 1):

You can view the [“hottest” questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot). Hotness is calculated from the number of views, votes and answers, with recent views/votes/answers weighing a lot more than old ones.

You can easily see [the highest-scored questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes), and also fairly easily see [the highest-scored answers (`is:answer`)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer). You can't sort by views, but you can search for [questions with at least X views (`views:X`)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A1000).

If you'd like to analyze the data further, you can get it in parsable form through the [API](http://api.scifi.stackexchange.com/). With barely 1000 questions, you can just retrieve them all [from `/questions`](http://api.scifi.stackexchange.com/1.1/usage/methods/questions) (get `/questions?sort=creation&order=asc&pagesize=100&page=N` for N=1..9 at present). The data includes the view and vote count.

---

The moderator tools includes various statistics, including total page views across the site, main referrers and common search keywords. The specifics are confidential, but here are a few trends:

- The total page views have more than doubled in May compared to April. (They were *lower* in April than in Feb-Mar; we've come back a little above the February level.)
- The increase is even larger for the number of new visits (which remained about the same level between late Jan and mid-Apr, then started to rise).
- Search engines now account for more than 40% of the traffic.
- It's hard to tell with the search keywords, because the reporting is [buggy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92915/strange-results-in-search-keywords-analytics). But *Doctor Who* comes up a lot, with *Star Trek* and *Game of Thrones* far behind.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the list of the subject of the most great answers, again in no particular order. For reference, there is 33 answers that are great answers right now.

- 3 Dr. Who
- 3 BattleStar Galactica
- 2 Dune
- 7 Lord of the Rings
- 1 Firefly
- 5 Star Wars
- 1 Stargate
- 1 Harry Potter
- 3 Star Trek
- 1 Issac Asimov
- 1 List questions
- 1 Super Heros
- 1 Blade Runner
- 1 Matrix
- 1 General Technology
- 1 Hitchhiker's Guide